# Building rpm

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

Is there an easy procedure to build an RPM.If so Please explain or provide the link.........

My requirement is very simple ..

I have two other RPMs which should be combined into one single RPM....

Please explain the process....

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: What you ask and what you want to achieve are not very related. In full car tradition, what you asked sounds like: how can you build an engine from scratch ? I need to change the oil pump. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building an RPM itself is rather easy, you just need to run

```
rpmbuild -ba <mypackage.spec>
```

The more complex task is creating the `.spec` file, which controls how the rpm itself is built. A good explanation is the book [Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/), which is available on the rpm homepage. Creating a `.spec` file is handled [here](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html). From my own experience building a `.spec` file is something that's not easy -- but not too complicated either unless you want to make special things. The standard `./configure && make && make install` is usually not too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is; if you've already got two RPMs, why do you need to make them into 1 rpm? Why not just use a shell script to install them both at the same time?

The RPM command will take multiple arguments, so for example:

```
rpm -ivh one.rpm two.rpm three.rpm
```

Will install one, followed by two, followed by three.

Otherwise, from what I know, you're going to have to build the packages first, and then build them into an RPM, at which point you will have a custom RPM that will have to be manually updated every time one of the component packages changes. Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

Basic guide for RPM creation is available at:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

A very good and complete guide for RPM creation (by Fedora community) is available at link: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/

It is is wonderful.

BTW, for straight answer of your question, you might want to add two packages as a subpackage of another package. For that there are some specific entries in RPM spec file.

You need to create only one SPEC file for all three packages